# How to get the UIVIewController's IBOutlet list programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

I am building one framework. I need to get the IBOutels list from UIViewcontroller through code. I have written `InterfaceOutletsReadable` protocol. If the  framework user conforms this protocol I have to read the list of IBOutlets from ViewController.

```
 protocol InterfaceOutletsReadable {
     ///Read the outlets objects
     func readOutlets()
 }
 extension InterfaceOutletsReadable {
    //TODO:- Stuck at this stage. Here I have to read the viewcontroller IBOutlets
 }
 class HomeViewController: InterfaceOutletsReadable {
     @IBOutlet weak var userNameTextField: UITextField!
     @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
     @IBOutlet weak var errorLabel: UILabel!
 }
```

**Edit**: I don't want to get the list from IBOutlet Collection. Is there any way to get all outlets programmatically?

Comment: Then what is the issue?

Comment: @dahiya_boy Its a framework project. I have to get the list of outlets from ViewController. Not through IBOutlet collection.How to get that?

Answer (score 2):

you can take `IBOutletCollection` of one `textField` and connect to all others.It maintain Array of Outlet and You Can access through index.

Answer (score 1):

`@IBOutlets` exist only at design time, there are no ones even at compile time. So it’s imposible to get all outlets in the way you want. Outlets have no difference with other variables.

If you need list of the outlets you may implement `readOutlets()` in your `HomeViewController` and `return Array` consist any variables you want.